# Share to facebook on flutter WEB

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is there a way that one can use to share some content of your FLUTTER WEB app to social media websites? There are libraries for Android and iOS that doesn't work on the web platform because there exist no configurations for Web.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/#settings and generate a share button, after that you can copy the link generated for that button and then you can use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to create a button which when pressed goes to that specific link.

Comment: it's only static.. I want to do it dynamically and set thumbnails for each link as well...